# Is it possible to take the last folder in the path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need to get the last folder or element after slash in the path. In other words I have:

```
path = '/Users/ivanmac/Desktop/dogs_vs_cel/thumbnails_features_deduped_sample/'
```

and I need to get:

```
'thumbnails_features_deduped_sample'
```

from it.

```
for d, _, files in os.walk(path):
    print(d[4])  # would be great to have something like this..
```

How to do it nicely, maybe someone knows?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a fuller answer, but look at os.path - it's for precisely this sort of manipulation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

Use [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename):

```
>>> os.path.basename('/Users/ivanmac/Desktop/dogs_vs_cel/thumbnails_features_deduped_sample/')
'thumbnails_features_deduped_sample'
```

You can also use [`normpath`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to accommodate the trailing `/`:

```
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.normpath('/Users/ivanmac/Desktop/dogs_vs_cel/thumbnails_features_deduped_sample/'))
```